# Different results after creating two JS objects from (seemingly) identical JSON

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-form

I'll try to frame this in a framework-agnostic manner, but my use case is specific to `react`/`redux`/`redux-form`.

I first get a `thing` out of the store. This is important because if I define this object in place, things work fine. It makes it really difficult to reacreate the error, though. So, I'll go through a couple examples. The first one works, the rest don't. Let's say it has the following structure:

```
thing = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: ['bar'],
  baz: 'baz'
}
```

This works fine

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { thing } = state.thing;
  // thing = {
  //   foo: 'foo',
  //   bar: ['bar'],
  //   baz: 'baz'
  // }

  // I don't care about `baz`, and I don't want to send it downstream
  // If I hardcode this, everything works fine
  // (except that my data is dynamic, so 
  // this is not a real solution)
  const workingObj = { foo: 'foo', bar: ['bar'] }

  return (
    { initialValues: workingObj }
  );
}
```

This doesn't work, however

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { thing } = state.thing;
  const brokenObj = { foo: thing.foo, bar: thing.bar };
  return (
    { initialValues: brokenObj }
  );
}
```

I figured I was having some issue with references losing scope or something. Let's try a deep copy:

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { thing } = state.thing;
  const brokenObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(
    { foo: thing.foo, bar: thing.bar }
  );

  return (
    { initialValues: brokenObj }
  );
}
```

Here's that same one in more detail... I have no idea how workingObjStr and brokenObjStr could be parsed into anything other than identical objects.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { thing } = state.thing;
  const workingObj = { foo: 'foo', bar: ['bar'] };
  const brokenObj = { foo: thing.foo, bar: thing.bar };

  const workingObjStr = JSON.stringify(workingObj);
  const brokenObjStr = JSON.stringify(brokenObj);
  console.debug(workingObjStr === brokenObjStr);
  // => true

  return (
    { initialValues: JSON.parse(brokenObjStr) }
  );
}
```

So, my question in general terms is: **how could two identical string objects produce different objects after being parsed**? Might there be some optimization voodoo going on behind the scenes, or am I missing something fundamental? I can't imagine how anything downstream of this return would even *know* that these objects have been produced through different means, so I'm completely stumped.

I'll also note again that I can't really think of how you could reproduce this... it seems somehow tied to the `redux` environment, because if I define the `thing` object inside the function scope things work fine.

I'll also say that I *know* the `initialValues` object is properly formatted and is propagating downstream because I can see it inside of my form... but `redux-form` doesn't pick it up unless it is created manually inside of the `mapStateToProps` function scope. Again, I have no idea how it would even be able to tell the difference, but hopefully I'm just missing something silly...

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: With `{ reservation.foo, reservation.bar }` are you looking for `{ foo: reservation.foo, bar: reservation.bar }`? You're missing the property names for that object. You also never use `thing` in any of your examples.

Comment: Does this even work? The `{ reservation.foo, reservation.bar }` part is pure SyntaxError.

Comment: Code has been updated to better reflect reality. This isn't the real code, I've tried to generalize it a bit more to demonstrate the problem without the full context.

Comment: My bet is that you either want `const { thing } = state;` or `const thing = state.thing;` but not `const { thing } = state.thing;`

Comment: "*how could two identical string objects produce different objects after being parsed?*" - you seem to mean that they produce the same JSON. They are however distinct objects with different identities of course. Whether that matters we can only tell if you show us the code that uses these objects and produces the unexpected results.